# This new puzzle type needs a name {3}

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, reverse-puzzling

I believe I have invented** a new type of puzzle...

> **What is its name?**

<sub>** *Well, 'adapted' an existing one, really...*</sub>

[image]

<sup>*Colour-blind-friendly version available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3O4e.png). Those without colour-blindness may still find this link useful for differentiating between colours of different shades which appear similar...*</sup>

Apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) (!) and discover its name!

---

<sup>*Other puzzles in the 'This new puzzle type needs a name' theme: [01](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [02](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92586/another-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name)*</sup>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Part 1

> I believe this is three Masyu puzzles in red, blue, and yellow superimposed on each other.
>  The red puzzle follows the logic of red, orange, and purple.
> [image]
>  The blue puzzle follows the logic of blue, green, and purple.
> [image]
>  The yellow puzzle follows the logic of yellow, green, and orange.
> [image]
>  And just for completeness, the three puzzle solutions together.
> [image]

The final solution (finally)

> The name of the puzzle is MASSYU
>  By reducing each solution to just the cells that the loop passes through and overlaying them, the cells that all three puzzles pass through spell out 'MASSYU'
>  The colour mixing idea from the initial three puzzles helped to indicate this solution.
> [image]
>  I'm guessing the name is a portmanteau of MASS and MASYU, since it certainly is more complex.

Comment: Excellent work! Well done for finding all 3 sub-puzzles and finding their solutions perfectly :) Now for the name. You're *so nearly there*. That final diagram will prove to be very useful (although not necessarily exactly as you've currently drawn it...).

Comment: That's what I'm struggling to figure out. I figured I'd post what I've got so far. The three puzzles were quite challenging, very well made!

Comment: Thanks :) I've been working on this one on and off for weeks - you won't believe how hard it was to create 3 inter-relating puzzles on one grid! Especially 3 which end up producing the solution in the way you still need to work out... +1 for the good work so far!

Comment: Bingo! Well done :) The checkmark is yours. Thanks for seeing it through to the end!

Comment: Thanks! I've really come to like masyu puzzles, especially those with a twist. I look forward to your next puzzle!

Comment: Just for completeness to show how the clue guides you to the name, one can note that paint-mixing rules apply, where combining all three colours leads to brown paint; and the bottom of the image indicates that brown paint gives the name of the puzzle.

Comment: The paint mixing logic is only really important for separating the puzzle into three sub-puzzles. The final answer is simply the intersection of all three (the colour is unimportant), although the idea of colour mixing helped to reach this solution.