# This new puzzle type needs a name {4}

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, sudoku, reverse-puzzling

I believe I have invented a new type of puzzle...

> **What is its name?**

[image]

Begin by solving the 16x16 sudoku; each of the digits 1-16 must appear exactly once in each row, column and thick-bordered 4x4 box. Then apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) (!) and discover its name!

**Hint 1:**

> Notice that in the second-step grid-deduction puzzle (solved by @athin) there were several trivial 1's that could be resolved immediately. Clearly they were not that important to resolving the rest of the grid - but they must have been included for another reason, right??

**Hint 2:**

> The message that has been encoded in the final solved puzzle is 16 letters long.

**Hint 3:**

> Consider the trivial 1 in the bottom row of the second-step grid-deduction puzzle... If this had been omitted, 2 letters in the hidden message would have been corrupted and unreadable.

---

<sup>*Other puzzles in the 'This new puzzle type needs a name' theme: [01](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [02](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92586/another-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [03](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92922/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-3)*</sup>

Comment: I feel like I know the answer, but I don't have a clue how to actually extract it from the puzzle, even with the hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution for the Sudoku, H is 'H'ighlighted with yellow color.

> [image]

As pointed by Deusovi, this is:

> Herugolf puzzle

And here is the solution.

> [image]

Thanks to Johnson, to extract the final answer:

> For each row, mark all cells with no line passing them. You will see that sometimes it is just a single marked cell or two adjacent marked cells. We can then treat them as Morse code!
>
>  `-- -.-- -. .- -- . .. ... ... ..- -.. --- --. --- .-.. ..-.`
>
>  Resulting "my name is **sudogolf**".

Comment: I believe now it should be a Herugolf?

Comment: @Deusovi Ah that must be it! I just know about that puzzle tho

Comment: Well done athin - all correct so far! +1 Find how I've encoded the name and the checkmark is yours...

Comment: @athin Perhaps A1Z26?

Comment: As a hint, I chose my words in my previous comment very carefully and deliberately. One of them could be italicised for emphasis... If still unsolved in 24 hours I'll post a hint more widely...

Comment: You've done all the heavy lifting - I believe the final answer is extracted by rot13(gerngvat rnpu yvar nf n zbefr-rapbqrq yrggre, sbphffvat ba gur erznvavat fdhnerf. Gjb gbtrgure vf n qnfu, bar ol vgfrys n qbg.) When you do that, the name makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Just beat me to it!  Nice solve athin and Johnson, and great puzzle Stiv!

Comment: @Johnson wow very great spot there! I'm devastated by the encoding, I've gone too far and totally missed that

Comment: Well done @Johnson, and well done athin - it is finished! Here's that checkmark!