# This new puzzle type needs a name {5}

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, sudoku, calculation-puzzle, reverse-puzzling

I believe I have invented a new type of puzzle...

> **What is its name?**

[image]

<sup>*Colour-blind-friendly version available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOMrF.png).*</sup>

Begin by solving the 9x9 sudoku; each of the 9 symbols `/`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `=`, `^`, `>`, `v` and `<` must appear exactly once in each row, column and thick-bordered 3x3 box. Then apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) (!) and discover its name!

**Hint 1:**

> Every colour used in this puzzle is there to help you solve it, whether for deriving and solving the second-stage grid-deduction puzzle or deriving its name. *Every* colour...

**Hint 2:**

> [sudoku](/questions/tagged/sudoku) then [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) then [arithmetic](/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

---

<sup>*Other puzzles in the 'This new puzzle type needs a name' theme: [01](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [02](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92586/another-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [03](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92922/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-3), [04](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93372/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-4)*</sup>

Comment: I think it's time for another hint

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First...

> ... solve the Sudoku, as instructed.
>
>  Credit to dcfyj and Kevin Cruijssen for solving this step first.
>
>  The completed grid, as depicted by Kevin Cruijssen, looks like this:
>
>  [image: The completed Sudoku grid.]

Next...

> ... solve the 5x5 [Futoshiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki) puzzle formed by the white squares and the red-circle inequality symbols between them.
>
>  The finished grid looks like this:
>
>  [image: The completed Futoshiki grid.]

Finally...

> ... we apply the color-coded arithmetic symbols to each row and column.  There are four symbols in each row/column (plus an equals sign), which fits perfectly!
>
>  Standard order of operations apply.  The completed grid reveals our answer.
>
>  [image: The completed arithmetic.]

The new puzzle type's name is...

> **SUDOSHIKI**.

Great construction, Stiv!

Comment: Great job at wrapping this up, mbingo :) Could you include the sudoku image from the comment by @KevinCruijssen (with credit, of course) at the start of your answer for completeness? That would make for a nice comprehensive solution... Then the checkmark will be yours! Thanks :)

Comment: Done!  And again, excellent puzzle (and series)!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks mbingo. I figured Kevin's great diagram needed to be given some 'airtime' rather than being hidden away in the comments. This rounds it off nicely. Have a checkmark!

Comment: How are you fill color slots after the first step?

Comment: Hi @Nick - the symbols in the grid are the ones which result from solving the sudoku (using the symbols instead of numbers 1-9). You then fill the coloured patches around the outside with the symbols from the corresponding region of the same shape & colour within the grid. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial Solution:

Here's the Sudoku solved

> [image: Solved Sudoku with colors]

So far I'm not really seeing any viable paths using both the colors and the solved Sudoku symbols. I do see that red

> only uses > < V for its symbols.

Which I find interesting, but I'm not sure how to use it. Also, because of the first hint I noticed that

> every color clue rests on a gray line, which implies to me that they all should, but if I use the arrows as viable color slots I have too many options, and if I use the arrows for red highlights only, I have too few for the other colors (provided I only place them on the gray)

Which basically just says, I'm still at a loss lol but at least I feel like I'm making a little progress

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Was working on it as well: [spoiler] https://i.stack.imgur.com/X983n.png [/spoiler]. ;)

Comment: Oh! thanks for the clue, @KevinCruijssen, I hadn't thought about doing that

Comment: I'd say that finding in your last spoiler (right now) may well be puh-retty relevant... Keep going!

Comment: @Stiv I figured it was, I'm just not seeing how at the moment. I'll give it a proper look see later today when I have time.