# Pandiagonal Magic Takuzu

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

Here's a puzzle type I call Pandiagonal Magic Takuzu. It's inspired by @Stiv's series ["This new puzzle type needs a name"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93830/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-5), except you get the name up front. Can you solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title means:

> [Pandiagonal Magic Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandiagonal_magic_square) + [Takuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuzu)

The first puzzle:

> There are 16 3×3 blocks which are numbered 1 to 16. Rearrange them to form a pandiagonal magic square. However, the bold ones(7, 9 and 13) are fixed and cannot be moved.
>
>  There are two such arrangements:
>
>
>  [image: magicsquare]

The second puzzle:

> The first solution is not a valid Takuzu puzzle, because it has four consecutive white cells on the second row. The second one has a unique solution:
>
>
>  [image: solution]

Comment: Nice work! +1 Perhaps you could explain more explicitly that in the first step you have rearranged the 3x3 blocks based on their central numbers, as per the magic square - as it took a little while for me to suss what was going on while reading through? Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks for the comment! I added more explanation about it.

Comment: You got it. Well done!